# A few issues with the custom filters experience

Tags: bug, user-experience, custom-questions-list

### Call to Attention

When you don't have any watched tags, this little text will give you a reason why you should have some:

> Watch tags to curate your list of questions.

[image]

There is a similar text for creating a custom filter, but I don't think it is put at the most logical place.

That dropdown menu is only available after you click on the "Create a saved filter" link on the right-hand side and after you click on the "More" button.

Also note that the *"call to attention"* message covers the form that lets you create your first custom filter. That's getting in the way IMHO.

[image]

*Suggestion: the text could be clickable too so that it triggers the form if it was initially hidden*

---

### The 'Unanswered (my tags)' filter does not automatically update

[image]

This may be by design, but this *seems* like an easy thing to do and a nice to have.

---

### Impossible to delete "unsaved" filter

Oddly enough this only occurs on *Meta* Stack Overflow.

As you can see I have this `Custom (unsaved)` filter which I have never created (or attempted to create).

But let's assume it is a user error. When I click on it then go to `Filter` and save it. After I delete it, I'm left with the same "ghost" filter:

[image]